# Ubuntu 16.04 python can not import my modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I've got a folder named aspects where there are 2 files: Aspects.py and Main.py. I'm using the class from Aspects.py in Main.py. There is a line `from aspects.Aspects import Aspects` there and on Mac OS I've got no problems running my program. But I need to run it on Ubuntu, so I do this:

```
python3 Main.py
```

but get the problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from aspects.Aspects import Aspects
ImportError: No module named 'aspects'
```

Please, help me!

Comment: 1) Is the directory containing the aspect dir in the python path, 2) Is there also a `__init__.py` in the aspect directory?

Comment: Yes, but the file is empty, what should I write there?

Comment: Empty is fine. What does "import aspects" do by itself?

Comment: import the Aspects class from Aspects.py file

Answer (score 0):

If your `aspects` folder structure as follows:

```
- aspects/ 
    - __init__.py 
    - Aspect.py 
    - Main.py
```

To import Aspect module into your main:

```
#Main.py 
from . import Aspect
Aspect.classname
```

Comment: It works fine on my Mac, but fails with the same error as above on Ubuntu

Comment: try `from Aspect import SomeClass` if still error. Check current working dir(`import os os.getcwd()`)

Comment: it also didn't help on Ubuntu, however everything is correct on mac( the current working dir is correct